# Purpose of non-Jews

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles

I was having a conversation with a friend about the purpose of life. I remember learning somewhere that the purpose of non-Jews is to build up the physical world, while the purpose of Jews is to spiritually elevate the world.

Does anyone know the source of this?

Comment: I understood that the main purpose of non-Jews was so that Jews could have "Shabbat Goyim" :-) Seriously, I think the main reason was to have a group of people to which Jews could demonstrate and teach their morals to.

Comment: I asked this question to different people and received various metaphorical answers. A very frustrating one was "they were made to be wedding guests." Somewhat better was "a body for the head." I do not agree with any of these and think a better question is why Jews were made.

Comment: @SAH "a better question is why Jews were made" - Granted, we have a bias to ask the OP's question. But, I can see that this a valid point, as the concept of "Jews" emanated much later. It begs a more basic question as to whether G-d created "Jews" or Jews were formed because someone recongnized G-d. Otherwise, Jews would have never been around.

Comment: If Goyim didn’t exist, being Jewish would be a lot simpler (i.e. less persecution, less immoral temptations, etc.) Maybe it has something to do with existing as a challenge of sorts?